# Scala program running very slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running Scala Spark program in yarn mode and program does not complete even after 30 min, so had to cancel the job. Kindly let me know what tuning needs to be done to make program run faster.

Have limited knowledge on Scala.

Same program we had written in PySpark it completes within 10 mins.

Algorithm is not that complex. No joins. I learnt scala first then started coding but not as good as Python.

1. Create dataframe from from file
2. Lookup data is loaded to list and broadcast
3. Send 3 columns to sub program, which calculates amounts (no complex calculation) and get description from lookup data and return single value back to the dataframe.
4. Write the data to CSV file.
5. Creating UDF from the sub progrm

Record count : 140 million
Size : 30 GB
Columns : 21
Number of part files : 200

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--driver-memory 5G \
--executor-cores=3 \ 
--executor-memory=4G \ 
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=512 \ 
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=512 \ 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=5 \ 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=10 \ 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=5 \ 
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \ 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" \ 
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" \ 
--class org.spark.masking.MainProgram ./ScalaProgramming.jar'
```

Below log is from GC. Kindly let me know if any other log is required.

There was huge list of flags, which i could not post it here.

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark" \

2.213: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 0K(1398144K)] 536935K(2027264K), 0.1361808 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.04, real=0.13 secs] 
2.349: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2.350: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2.350: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2.350: [Preclean SoftReferences, 0.0000071 secs]2.350: [Preclean WeakReferences, 0.0000046 secs]2.350: [Preclean FinalReferences, 0.0000045 secs]2.350: [Preclean PhantomReferences, 0.0000048 secs]2.353: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.003/0.003 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2.353: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2.467: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2.467: [ParNew2.480: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000342 secs]2.480: [WeakReference, 701 refs, 0.0000763 secs]2.480: [FinalReference, 7789 refs, 0.0201415 secs]2.500: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 3 refs, 0.0000190 secs]2.500: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000281 secs]: 559232K->25830K(629120K), 0.0335811 secs] 559232K->25830K(2027264K), 0.0336755 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.04, real=0.04 secs] 
3.814: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 1.065/1.462 secs] [Times: user=5.10 sys=0.25, real=1.46 secs] 
3.815: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 307047 K (629120 K)]3.815: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0060711 secs]3.821: [weak refs processing3.821: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000093 secs]3.821: [WeakReference, 0 refs, 0.0000066 secs]3.821: [FinalReference, 0 refs, 0.0000063 secs]3.821: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 0 refs, 0.0000079 secs]3.821: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000094 secs], 0.0000570 secs]3.821: [class unloading, 0.0062279 secs]3.827: [scrub symbol table, 0.0056485 secs]3.833: [scrub string table, 0.0005033 secs][1 CMS-remark: 0K(1398144K)] 307047K(2027264K), 0.0197652 secs] [Times: user=0.14 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
3.835: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
3.835: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
3.835: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
3.864: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.029/0.029 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.03, real=0.03 secs] 
8.655: [GC (Allocation Failure) 8.655: [ParNew8.668: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000357 secs]8.668: [WeakReference, 1908 refs, 0.0001536 secs]8.668: [FinalReference, 8067 refs, 0.0204567 secs]8.689: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 9 refs, 0.0000229 secs]8.689: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000224 secs]: 585062K->40277K(629120K), 0.0336923 secs] 585062K->40277K(2027264K), 0.0337921 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.02, real=0.03 secs] 
13.569: [GC (Allocation Failure) 13.569: [ParNew13.615: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000415 secs]13.615: [WeakReference, 841 refs, 0.0001029 secs]13.615: [FinalReference, 2145 refs, 0.0053077 secs]13.620: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 13 refs, 0.0000211 secs]13.620: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000214 secs]: 599509K->69888K(629120K), 0.0506452 secs] 599509K->148597K(2027264K), 0.0507616 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.11, real=0.06 secs] 
15.596: [GC (Allocation Failure) 15.596: [ParNew17.013: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000447 secs]17.013: [WeakReference, 444 refs, 0.0000785 secs]17.013: [FinalReference, 8380 refs, 0.0125680 secs]17.026: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 3 refs, 0.0000196 secs]17.026: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000143 secs]: 629120K->69888K(629120K), 1.4302181 secs] 707829K->260902K(2027264K), 1.4303383 secs] [Times: user=31.46 sys=0.10, real=1.43 secs] 
19.026: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 191014K(1398144K)] 574937K(2027264K), 0.0405526 secs] [Times: user=0.39 sys=0.01, real=0.04 secs] 
19.067: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
19.117: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.048/0.050 secs] [Times: user=0.88 sys=0.01, real=0.05 secs] 
19.117: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
19.117: [Preclean SoftReferences, 0.0000081 secs]19.117: [Preclean WeakReferences, 0.0000339 secs]19.117: [Preclean FinalReferences, 0.0000053 secs]19.117: [Preclean PhantomReferences, 0.0000060 secs]19.122: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.005/0.005 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
19.122: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
21.344: [GC (Allocation Failure) 21.345: [ParNew22.007: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000454 secs]22.007: [WeakReference, 4452 refs, 0.0004887 secs]22.008: [FinalReference, 4098 refs, 0.0080919 secs]22.016: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 11 refs, 0.0000249 secs]22.016: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000233 secs]: 629120K->69724K(629120K), 0.6716374 secs] 820134K->384114K(2027264K), 0.6719494 secs] [Times: user=14.39 sys=0.21, real=0.67 secs] 
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 24.240: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 3.341/5.119 secs] [Times: user=23.16 sys=0.40, real=5.12 secs] 
24.241: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 230617 K (629120 K)]24.241: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0045982 secs]24.246: [weak refs processing24.246: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000095 secs]24.246: [WeakReference, 0 refs, 0.0000068 secs]24.246: [FinalReference, 0 refs, 0.0000064 secs]24.246: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 0 refs, 0.0000083 secs]24.246: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000154 secs], 0.0000646 secs]24.246: [class unloading, 0.0243305 secs]24.270: [scrub symbol table, 0.0141372 secs]24.284: [scrub string table, 0.0009220 secs][1 CMS-remark: 314389K(1398144K)] 545007K(2027264K), 0.0463381 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.01, real=0.04 secs] 
24.288: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
24.336: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.049/0.049 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
24.336: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
24.391: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.055/0.055 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.05, real=0.06 secs] 
87.840: [GC (Allocation Failure) 87.840: [ParNew88.140: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000504 secs]88.140: [WeakReference, 1758 refs, 0.0002394 secs]88.140: [FinalReference, 5047 refs, 0.0074780 secs]88.148: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 16 refs, 0.0000204 secs]88.148: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000115 secs]: 614858K->69888K(629120K), 0.3078355 secs] 913711K->452374K(2027264K), 0.3080004 secs] [Times: user=6.56 sys=0.32, real=0.31 secs] 
616.341: [GC (Allocation Failure) 616.341: [ParNew616.377: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000486 secs]616.377: [WeakReference, 1923 refs, 0.0001649 secs]616.377: [FinalReference, 467 refs, 0.0009059 secs]616.378: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 24 refs, 0.0000197 secs]616.378: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000125 secs]: 629120K->35351K(629120K), 0.0365310 secs] 1011606K->445836K(2027264K), 0.0366766 secs] [Times: user=0.42 sys=0.12, real=0.03 secs] 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 3 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
Heap
 par new generation   total 629120K, used 293922K [0x0000000680000000, 0x00000006aaaa0000, 0x00000006eaaa0000)
  eden space 559232K,  46% used [0x0000000680000000, 0x000000068fc82d28, 0x00000006a2220000)
  from space 69888K,  50% used [0x00000006a6660000, 0x00000006a88e5e60, 0x00000006aaaa0000)
  to   space 69888K,   0% used [0x00000006a2220000, 0x00000006a2220000, 0x00000006a6660000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1398144K, used 410484K [0x00000006eaaa0000, 0x0000000740000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 97258K, capacity 98404K, committed 98636K, reserved 1134592K
  class space    used 13754K, capacity 14029K, committed 14116K, reserved 1048576K
```

Comment: can you also add the code ?

Comment: I think If the same program runs in Python in 10 minutes, then the "tuning" will be "rewriting", and someone will need to learn Scala (that's generally true of any programming language someone wants to write programs in).

Comment: with out seeing the code/spark-submit it will be guess work to answer this question

Comment: "faster"? About what are we talking here? Which algorithm on which dataset and which machine? We need to know complexity of the algorithm and size of the data, otherwise it's nonsense to continue here. Note, there is always a chance that things just need time they need ... also, comparing Scala vs Python code can only be done by yourself as we do **not** know any line of code so far ...

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd stop running with all the garbage collection output being logged.  It's not going to help you much, because garbage collection is part of any normal running program.

Second, I'd look at a few things:

1. How big is your data set?
2. What does your algorithm look like?

If the algorithm joins multiple RDDs and then filters them, attempt to filter one (or both) of the input RDDs first, and then join.  This creates fewer records participating in the join.

As far as speed; well, that's somewhat dependent on the data set size, and also dependent on the algorithm.

If you haven't studied it yet, look at what a shuffle is.  If you can reduce the number of shuffles, and defer them to the end of the processing, often you get faster program.

--- Edit after more information was added ---

It seems that you are processing about 30 GB in 4 GB chunks.  Odds are there are quite a few intermediate objects created and discarded which causes a high RAM churn within the 4GB chunks.  I'd look at your code, for any kind of pattern that heavily uses objects (like multiple string concatenations, not on one line or not using a format method.

Also, you've tuned your JVM to use perhaps the slowest garbage collector available.  By shifting to the parallel garbage collector, you should get a speed gain of about 27%, and using G1 should give you a gain of about 22%.  Keep in mind the differences in speed also come with differences in memory overhead, so monitor GC tuning in both RAM and speed changes.

Finally, if you are maintaining a very large RDD in RAM, check to see if your Spark jobs are spilling to disk.  Without both sets of code (Python and Scala) it's difficult to see what the job intends to do, and if it is doing it in an inefficient manner under Spark.

Comment: @vickybangre please edit your question and put all those things there instead of here as comments.

Comment: Thanks edwin, i will check my code for your points and tune the code accordingly. Sharing code would be security issue, can't share it.